Does information about private heliports need to be published in the AIP?
I am seeking information on what international regulations specify regarding the publication of aeronautical data for a private heliports.

Only aerodromes (and heliports) participating to the international coordination of civil aviation, via the worldwide aeronautical fixed telecommunication network (AFTN), have to be listed in the AIP.
These coordinated aerodromes (and heliports) are open to any public operator, for civil traffic. They offer VFR and/or IFR services. Some are military.

The aeronautical information publication is a set of professional documents to facilitate international civil aviation under the recommendation of the ICAO, the international civil aviation organization. The documentation is described in annex 15 to the Chicago Convention. It includes aerodrome (and heliport) descriptions in section AD. Not all these aerodromes offer border controls, but they can be used for operations within the country after border controls have be satisfied. All airports in section AD are part of the AFTN network, and have an AFTN location identifier ("ICAO code").
However, the AIP is not concerned by private aerodromes/airfields/heliports where international public operators cannot land and take off. Note private is used in the sense of "restricted to private operations", as many privately owned aerodromes and airports are open to international aviation.
Aerodromes listed in the AIP cannot prohibit a public operator to use their facilities, except for technical limitations (e.g. the runway length or the material used to build it), or for commercial reasons (applicable fees not paid by the operator).
From the US AIP:

International arrivals with scheduled passenger service are not permitted to land at any aerodrome not listed in this AIP except in cases of real emergency or where special permission has been granted.

This mention is a copy of the one found in ICAO Doc 8126 which details the content of the aeronautical information services (AIS).

This doesn't preclude to maintain other directories. E.g. the FAA maintains a directory which goes beyond AIP ICAO requirements, and includes all airfields and navigation facilities declared to the FAA, for various reasons.

Unfortunately the FAA database for those airports is wildly out of date. When I attempted to update the status of some of the non-fields near me, I was told that they do not have the manpower to validate the entries. They also didn't seem to have a timeline on acting on the reports I made. I looked into it because a drone pilot friend was having his flight operations restricted by a private field that had been converted to a housing subdivision.
